# R apply function with dynamic criteria

Tags: r, apply

I have a question when trying to use "apply" to a matrix instead of loops to improve efficiency. But the problem was each single output would be based on other cell's results. If I explain in excel table. For cell D6, if the sum of yellow cell < 5 (fixed number) and sum of blue cell < 4 (first column value), assign that cell value 1. Eventually, the value of 4 will be distributed across its rows with 4 x "1"s. (see attached pic)

tried some R code:
`dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(, nrow = 6, ncol = 5))

dat[,1]=c(2,3,4,3,4,5)
apply(dat[,2:5], 1:2, function(x){ifelse([...],1,0) })`

Not sure how to code in the bracket part.. 
Eventually, want to replace the value in dat with all outputs. Really appreciate!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is that after you update one cell then that newly updated cell is used by subsequent computations then you really need a double loop, not `apply`.

Note that the last row in the answer below differs from the answer shown in the question. I am assuming that that represents an error in the answer shown in the question.  If not please clarify the rules.

```
dat <- matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 5)
dat[,1] <- c(2,3,4,3,4,5)

for(j in 2:ncol(dat)) 
   for(i in 1:nrow(dat))
      dat[i,j] <- ( sum(dat[1:i, j]) - dat[i, j] < 5 ) * 
                  ( sum(dat[i, 2:j]) - dat[i, j] < dat[i, 1] )
dat
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    1    1    0    0
[2,]    3    1    1    1    0
[3,]    4    1    1    1    1
[4,]    3    1    1    1    0
[5,]    4    1    1    1    1
[6,]    5    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!! Yes, you were right. That's typo. Actually, I used double loops before. But the problem is, in practice there are thousands of rows and the number needs to be distributed are quite large, like 100. That gave me the running time over couple hours... Is there a way to optimize the process? like I was thinking in Excel, you can drag and apply the formula through entire row/column. Thanks!

Comment: Normally if you want to speed up iterative calculations one rewrites them in C++ using the Rcpp interface.

Comment: Also, one simple that you could do (I have modified the code in the answer to do it) is to use matrices instead of data frames -- accessing them is faster.